# Accessing SharePoint site list from Angular client

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

If I go to Microsoft's [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) and use a URL like:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/4development106.sharepoint.com:/sites/DBSchenker:/lists/OEC_Docs/items
```

I can see my request succeeds.

Now if I use the [Angular app](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js) from GitHub, and the code like

```
 private sharePointHost: string = "https://4development106.sharepoint.com/sites/DBSchenker/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('OEC_Docs')/items"

  getDocuments(token){
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Accept':  'application/json;odata=verbose'
          ,'Authorization' : "Bearer " + token
        })
      };

    this.http.get(this.sharePointHost, httpOptions).subscribe(
      (resp) => console.log("respon is::: " + JSON.stringify(resp)),
      (err) => console.log("error:::" + JSON.stringify(err))
    )
  }
```

It throws:

```
error:::{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"OK","url":"https://4development106.sharepoint.com/sites/DBSchenker/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('OEC_Docs')/items","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://4development106.sharepoint.com/sites/DBSchenker/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('OEC_Docs')/items: 401 OK","error":{"error_description":"Invalid JWT token. No certificate thumbprint specified in token header."}}
```

changing the host to (which works in the Graph API explorer)

```
private sharePointHost: string = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/4development106.sharepoint.com:/sites/DBSchenker:/lists/OEC_Docs/items"
```

throws

```
error:::{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":401,"statusText":"Unauthorized","url":"https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/4development106.sharepoint.com:/sites/DBSchenker:/lists/OEC_Docs/items","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sites/4development106.sharepoint.com:/sites/DBSchenker:/lists/OEC_Docs/items: 401 Unauthorized","error":{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure.","innerError":{"request-id":"f5a77afc-0d92-49a0-92c4-e727e056d0a9","date":"2018-10-30T01:42:02"}}}}
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you haven't added sufficient permissions for your app in Azure AD.

If you want to use MS Graph endpoint to access SharePoint data, you should add SharePoint permissions for MS Graph in Azure portal (SharePoint permissions correspond to "site collections"):
[image]

If you want to use direct SharePoint REST API (`https://4development106.sharepoint.com/sites/DBSchenker/_api/web...`), then you should Office 365 SharePoint Online permissions to your registered app:

[image]

Comment: where do i access azure AD. overall very confusing stuff as lot of documents indicate that if i am logged in then for local host i dont need to even worry about permissions. and while creating the app i did add Sites.ReadWriteAll

Comment: Open your Azure portal, then go Azure Active Directory management view, select your registered app, then under Settings -> Required permissions give the app all permissions you need

Comment: this is what i have for graph api: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gc8ziw9ehhjxihh/Screen%20Shot%202018-10-30%20at%2010.25.53%20AM.png?dl=0 

but this still fails with "error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"Access token validation failure."

Comment: and to mention i could not even find office 365 sharepoint apis. the one with closest name is share point apis which on clicking says use graph apis.

Comment: You use App registrations Preview, that's why you see a bit different UI. From your screen, it looks like permissions are good for accessing SharePoint from graph endpoint, but not from SharePoint REST. You should add SharePoint permissions using corresponding SharePoint link in preview or office 365 sharepoint apis in regular app registration view.   
For "Access token validation failure" - it seems there are some issues with your MSAL  implementation. I suggest asking at github issues about your problem.

Comment: well i thought preview is just a different UI not the behind the scene implementation. in other words, i thought giving permissions using preview should be enough. also to minimze, i dont need to get it working same time using graph as well as direct REST. i am fine whatever way works. so which one do u advise to use if i just pick one to narrow down my problem focus

Comment: just to add the app i can see using "app reg. preview" i can't find it in regular "app registations" link.